# Bridged network connection not working on Ubuntu VM

Tags: ubuntu, bridge, vmware-workstation

I am in a corporate environment and there is 802.1x authentication set up which is using my windows credentials + domain to authenticate. Setting up that information for my connection in the VM only keeps prompting me for the password.

I want to select the vmnet8 bridged connection which incorporates the same authentication settings, but that doesn't show up when I go to select the adapter in the vmware player settings - only my intel NIC.

Does anyone know what could be the problem? NAT works, but I need this VM to be accessible to other computers on the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your domain admin to join the VM to the domain.  Provide him/her the computer name or else change the computer name of your VM to match their naming convention that may be set to auto accept.

I had this same problem (large company) and this fixed it.

Now i see your Ubuntu tag, here is some more info:

http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/336477-how-to-join-a-ubuntu-machine-to-a-windows-domain

Basically, the same applies as above, but some add'l steps are needed:

1. Open up the Add/Remove Software tool. Search for "likewise open".
2. Mark likewise-open5, likewise-open5-gui, and winbind for installation (the Add/Remove tool will pick up any necessary dependencies for you).
3. Click Apply to install (and Apply to accept any dependencies).

That's it. You are now ready to join your Windows domain. 
Open up a terminal window and issue the following command:

`sudo domainjoin-cli join DOMAIN_NAME USER`

(Courtesy of Jack Wallen)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using PortMapper from AnalogX.  I forwarded my HTTP port on my host computer IP to the IP/HTTP port on my guest OS, using NAT connection.